# What is the expectation when <a> tag's href is a html file and download attribute is added?

Tags: html, anchor, epub

```
<a href='1.html' download> Download 1.html </a>
```

For example the above HTML code,
What should be the expectation when users clicks on the hyperlink??

1. Should redirect the users to 1.html
2. Should allow the users to download 1.html
3. Others?

As I am developing on a epub reader, would like to know the expectation of the above behavior of above case if the HTML (e.g. 1.html) is not included in the spine item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_a_download.asp), the `download` attribute does indeed do what you want: the file should be automatically downloaded instead of being viewed in the browser.

This is, of course, unrelated to whether the file `1.html` is included in the EPUB's spine - the spine indicates the reading order of the files from the manifest, and `1.html` could be in the EPUB or external, and even if in the manifest, it may or may not be in the spine! I guess you're trying to provide a download option in your EPUB reader for particular files from inside the EPUB package?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to provide a download option in the EPUB reader for the users to download such as PDF/ docx which files are also put in the EPUB package.
So I just wondered what would be the expectation if the <a> tag would redirect users to other pages when the href is xxx.html. 
But thanks for your answer, I just knew that the file should be automatically downloaded instead of being viewed in the browser.